# How to create a menu bar on OSX with PySide2?

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm looking at the [Data Visualization Tool Tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/datavisualize/add_mainwindow.html) on the QT website where they have an example of creating a menu bar inside a `QMainWindow`:

```
self.menu = self.menuBar()
self.file_menu = self.menu.addMenu("File")
```

This doesn't work for me on OSX 10.13.6. I've also tried using `QMenuBar` to create my own menu bar rather than using the default one that comes with a `QMainWindow`:

```
menu_bar = QMenuBar()
menu_bar.addMenu('File')
self.setMenuBar(menu_bar)
```

This also has no effect. I never see the "File" option in the menu bar of my app. I just get a generic menu bar with a single "python" option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it is working, but "File" will only appear once you add actions to the file menu.

```
menu = self.menuBar()
file = menu.addMenu('File')
file.addAction(QAction('Open...', self))
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. I copied and pasted the exit action right out of the example.

Comment: For what it's worth, even when I remove all the actions, I still get a non-native menu bar when I use call `setNativeMenuBar(False)` on the menu bar object. So unless native and non-native menu bars work differently in this regard, I don't think that wasn't the issue.

Comment: "Exit" probably has some significance then as a menu item, on the native menu bar. Try changing the exit action text to something else, like "Open", and see if the File option appears.

Comment: Wow, you're right! It didn't occur to me that QT might be doing something funny based on the string value. I set `exit_action = qtw.QAction("Something", self)`, and now I have a native menu bar with `File -> Something`. Thanks!